# HEREMaps error 5 when calculating long routes on iOS

Tags: here-api

UPDATE: This occurs only when using the simulator in Xcode. For this reason this question can be considered resolved. I'm not going to delete it though in case someone else experiences the same issue.

---

When I try to calculate routes for long distances (for example from Vancouver BC to New York NY I get an error back, error 5.

Error 5 is defined in the API as:

```
NMARoutingErrorInvalidOperation
There was an error due to another request already being processed.
```

This is however the same call that is made for other calculations without issue, this only happens for long distances.

Do you have any insight into what could be causing this? I have tried using both `fastest` and `balanced` for the routing type. I am using

```
router.calculateRoute(withStops: [startWaypoint, destinationWaypoint], routingMode: routingMode)
```

Going South I can calculate a route from Vancouver to Seattle (195Km) but not Aberdeen (250Km). Going East I can calculate to Skagit Provincial Park (150Km) but not to Manning Park (190 Km)

(iOS Premium License)

Comment: Maybe insufficient data? Is the simulator working in online mode?

Comment: @DavidLeong yeah it works fine for all requests except long distances. I unfortunately do not have time to debug why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs only when using the simulator in Xcode. For this reason this question can be considered resolved. I'm not going to delete it though in case someone else experiences the same issue.