# HERE API always respose NMARoutingErrorInvalidOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, here-api

I use the following function to get the optimal route.

```
https://wse.ls.hereapi.com/2/findsequence.json?start=25.082621,121.583021&destination1=25.097258,121.517384&destination2=25.041825,121.514988&destination3=25.026060,121.527532&destination4=25.034607,121.488616&destination5=25.063467,121.539141&destination6=25.070833,121.531389&destination7=25.023056,121.505278&destination8=25.093102,121.532366&destination9=25.094807,121.529036&destination10=25.075230,121.560761&destination11=25.093102,121.532366&destination12=25.118899,121.470798&mode=fastest;car&&apiKey=...
```

And try to use this (HERE SDK FOR IOS (PREMIUM EDITION) V3.17) :

```
NMARoutingMode *routingMode = [[NMARoutingMode alloc] initWithRoutingType:NMARoutingTypeFastest transportMode:NMATransportModeScooter routingOptions:NMARoutingOptionAvoidHighway];
NMACoreRouter *coreRouter = [[NMACoreRouter alloc] init];

coreRouter.connectivity = NMACoreRouterConnectivityOnline;

[coreRouter calculateRouteWithStops:stops routingMode:routingMode completionBlock:^(NMARouteResult * _Nullable routeResult, NMARoutingError error) {
}];
```

to bring out NMARouteResult, but it only respond NMARoutingErrorInvalidOperation

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Real device or simulator: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44207483/heremaps-error-5-when-calculating-long-routes-on-ios ?

Comment: Real device....

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that another request is already being processed. Please make sure you are not calling the route calculation until the result of the previous request is returned.